# How to dismiss alert dialog when clicked outside of it

Tags: flutter, dialog, android-alertdialog, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog that I want to be dismissed when clicked outside of it, I know this is the default behavior of alert dialogs in flutter, but I don't know what's the problem that's preventing it from closing when clicked outside.

I tried to use barrierDismissable to true, but still, it doens't work.

```
This is my dialog : 

termsAndConditionsDialog(BuildContext context) {

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title:  Text("Terms and Conditions", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: AppColors.accentColor),),
      content: Text(
        generalSettings.policyForCustomer,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),

    );


    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }


and this is how I call it from button's onPressed : 
 termsAndConditionsDialog(context);
```

Comment: Your code is right, i tried and dialog dismissing when i click outside. Can you share full code?

Comment: I think the problem is that I have a Gesture Detector in MyApp, which I use for the loading widget, when I remove it, everything works fine, is there a way that I can keep the gesture detector and also make the dialogs dismissable ?  ```builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return GestureDetector(
            onTap: ()=>FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
            child: LoadingProvider(
              child: Directionality(textDirection:TextDirection.rtl, child: child),
            ));
      },```

Answer (score 0):

call this upon onPressed or onTap:

```
void showMessage(){
  showDialog(
    context:context,
    builder: (Buildcontext context){
       return AlertDialog(
         backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
         content: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100,
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center
            child: Text("TRIAL",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
        )
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Alert method

```
typedef ResponseCallbackValueLess = void Function();

showAlertDialogWithOkButton(
  BuildContext context,
  String message,
  String heading,
  String buttonAcceptTitle,
  ResponseCallbackValueLess callback) {
Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
  child: Text(buttonAcceptTitle),
  onPressed: () {
    callback();
  },
);
```

called like below:

```
showAlertDialogWithOkButton(context,
                          'No items found in your cart.',
                          "app name", "Ok", dismissAlert(context));

dismissAlert(context){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```